# Kendo UI Listbox displaying duplicate items

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm using a Kendo UI Listbox control to display items. I'm populating the control by specifying a javascript array as the data source.

Here is the page markup.

```
<div>
  <select id="selectedview"></select> 
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#selectedview").kendoListBox();
    });
</script>
```

And here is the javascript / JQuery that I am using to populate the Kendo UI Listbox control.

```
var listBox = $("#selectedview").data("kendoListBox");
listBox.clearSelection();

$("#selectedview").kendoListBox({
    dataSource: subscribers
});
```

Here's the DataSource array that I am using.

[image]

When the control is displayed however the same two items are displayed multiple times in error.

[image]

What's going on and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be re-creating the widget over an already existent instance, that is why it is duplicating the items. [Check this out](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/oXAYUQoR).

If you want to update the list of an already created widget instance, try either:

1. Change the DataSource's [`data`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/data):

   ```
   $("#selectedview").data("kendoListBox").dataSource.data(subscribers);
   ```
2. To set [`setDataSource`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listbox/methods/setdatasource) again:

   ```
   $("#selectedview").data("kendoListBox").setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({ 
       data: subscribers
   });
   ```

Comment: Yes the issue definitely seems to be related to loading the control on subsequent page loads. On the initial page load the control works and loads the data perfectly. It's when updating the control the data is duplicated. I'll have a look at those suggestions :)

Comment: The second suggestion works for me. I'll mark as answer. Many thanks for your help I appreciate it :)

Comment: @DomBurf nice to hear that!! You're welcome. Good luck.